# Setting an attribute in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've got an application which simply takes a number of RSS feeds and stores them in a table. It checks a couple of things in each entry for conditions and then sets an attribute based on the condition.

```
if self.value1 > self.value2 then
    :status => 'foo'
else
    :status => 'bar'
end
```

I'm still a bit of a noob with Ruby/Rails and setting the status is causing an exception but I don't know why.

Any help would be great.

Comment: did you try self.status = 'foo' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "sets an attribute", I assume that you mean this is another column on the table. If so, this should work:

```
if self.value1 > self.value2
    update_attribute :status, "foo"
else
    update_attribute :status, "bar"
end
```

The "rocket" notation (`:this => "that"`) is used when instantiating an object, or when updating more than one attribute (`self.update_attributes :animal => "kitten", :sound => "Roar!"`). It's the notation that a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) uses.

You could also just use `status = "foo"`, but that will set the attribute without saving, so you'd also have to call `self.save`. `update_attribute` does both in one neat package.

Comment: Also, be aware that your validations will not happen with `update_attribute`; if you want your validations to run (and you probably do), use `update_attributes`, with the "s". [Check it out](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 I have done with the following method:

```
def update_test
  if self.value1 > self.value2
      self.status="foo"
  else
      self.status= "bar"
  end
end
```

and added before_update filter in model.

```
before_update :update_test, :if => :test_changed?
```

In this method we don't need to call the save or update_attributes this will be done in a single query.

Comment: This was nearly 3 years ago, I don't need help with it anymore.

Comment: I have added that if someone can get help form this snippet